# Are your TestFlight beta apps not being pushed out automatically?

Tags: objective-c, app-store-connect, testflight

I don't know if this began commensurate with the release of iOS 9 or Xcode 7.1, but for the past week or so, my app updates (which I am beta testing through TestFlight) that I upload to iTunesConnect are not being automatically pushed out to my test team.  Anyone seen this as well?

**Update 1:** I don't know if it is coincidental, but when (and only when) I go to iTunesConnect, select the app I am testing, then select the TestFlight tab, does the update get pushed...huh?

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to chime in and say that this is also occurring with some of my applications. We had one application test build not go out for 2 days because we didn't try to login to iTunes Connect.

Not entirely sure what is going on at Apples end, but it's definitely a weird bug...

Answer (score 0):

The Apple servers have been slow the past couple days effecting many different areas such as submitting apps, etc.